# How to change background color of <tr> when hovering over button inside of <td>?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to implement in either CSS, JavaScript, or HTML functionality that will change the background color of a table row (`<tr>`) when a button that is located within that table row's table data `<td>` is hovered over. By changing the CSS file I can easily accomplish changing the button's background color by assigning an id to the button, but don't know where to start to get the table row's background changed as well. I have looked at similar solutions on this website but they are not quite specific enough (the ones that I found anyway). Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please post a little code and read the FAQ. http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you will have to get a reference in JavaScript to all of the buttons in the table (you can get `document.getElementsByTagName` to get all buttons, `getElementsByName` if you give all of the buttons the same name (and no other elements), or `getElementsByClassName` if you give all of the buttons the same class (an no other elements).

```
// get all of the buttons in the table (I gave them all a class of tablebutton
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("tablebutton");
```

Next, you have to loop on the array of buttons and add two event listeners, one for the `mouseover` (hover over) event and one for the `mouseout` (hover away) event.

```
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    var button = buttons[i];
    button.addEventListener("mouseover", highlightRow, false);
    button.addEventListener("mouseout", unHighlightRow, false);
}
```

In those event listeners, you must traverse up the DOM tree from the button up to the table row and then set the background color for the row to either your highlighted color or "" to remove the color.

```
function highlightRow ()
{
    var row = this.parentNode.parentNode;
    row.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}

function unHighlightRow ()
{
    var row = this.parentNode.parentNode;
    row.style.backgroundColor = "";
}
```

(you could also just use anonymous functions instead of defining the functions with names...

```
    button.addEventListener("mouseover", function () {
        ...your code here
    }, false);
    button.addEventListener("mouseout", function () {
        ...your code here
    }, false);
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2z4nD/)

Comment: You can get all of the buttons in a table if you have an id on your table by doing this:  `document.getElementById("youridhere").getElementsByTagName("button")`

Comment: Two event handlers on every button is an incredibly inefficient way to go about it.

Comment: @cimmanon Is there another way in script handle the hover over an element besides mouseover and mouseout events?

Comment: I did not say there was anything wrong with mouseover/mouseout events, only that making one for each and every button that could possibly exist in the table is inefficient.

Comment: Ah.  Instead you could add a listener on the table itself, and check if the event target's tagName is `BUTTON`.

Answer (score 3):

jQuery:

```
$('table button').hover(function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

You really should spend some time reading the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/).

Comment: Nor did he say he didn't. He (or she) can take it or leave it. :-)

Comment: I'd usually agree with Derek, but your answer is fair enough, given the question. The comment you left up there, on the other hand...

Comment: Moreover, this jQuery answer is almost in English. It's a readable algorithm. And the only correct answer so far. That's why I upvoted it. The comment didn't sound quite adequate to me, nevertheless. When you posted it, the only answer was yours, and it was just seconds old.

Comment: I'm not sure what all the fuss is about... regardless THANK YOU everyone who has responded so far. Unfortunately I cannot use jQuery due to certain specifications, but thank you for the input.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try changing the `tr`'s hover styles?

http://jsfiddle.net/x2pLV/

```
table {
    width: 100%;
}

tr:hover {
    background: orange;
}

<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="submit" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The one problem with this is that it will change the color when hovering anywhere in the row and the question specified hovering over the button.

Answer (score 0):

I liked the idea of no jQuery, here's a fiddle:

```
var allButtons = document.getElementsByTagName('button'); 
for(var i=0; i < allButtons.length; ++i) { 
    if(allButtons[i].getAttribute('class') == "hoverme") { 
        allButtons[i].onmouseover = function() { makerow(this, 'blue'); };
        allButtons[i].onmouseout = function() { makerow(this, 'yellow'); };
    }
}

function makerow(elem, color) { 
    elem.parentNode.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = color; 
}
```

The code is somewhat dependent upon the structure of your table, so see attached for example: 
http://jsfiddle.net/JFd5T/

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want the highlight removed when leaving the row as well. In this case if you go for jQuery you'll need to remove that style as well but rather just go for a single action for both hover on and hover off

```
$("td.data").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).parent("tr").toggleClass("active");
 }
```

and add a style for that class in your css:

```
.active {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

you'll need to tweak the selector to match the cells or element you want to trigger the change but I can't see the markup so can't provide that exactly - the selector above has the class data on your data cells.

Btw I agree that a non jquery solution such as Scott's is the way to go if you're not already using jQuery.